# Converting a void* to a std::string

Tags: c++, string, printf, void-pointers

After perusing the web and messing around myself, I can't seem to convert a void*'s target (which is a string) to a std::string. I've tried using `sprintf(buffer, "%p", *((int *)point));` as recommended by [this page](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread221261.html) to get to a C string, but to no avail. And sadly, yes, I have to use a void*, as that's what SDL uses in their USEREVENT struct.

The code I'm using to fill the Userevent, for those interested, is:

```
std::string filename = "ResumeButton.png";
SDL_Event button_press;
button_press.type = BUTTON_PRESS;
button_press.user.data1 = &filename;
SDL_PushEvent(&button_press);
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Thanks for all the responses, I just needed to cast the void* to a std::string*. Silly me. Thank you guys so much!

Comment: What  is STL, what is USEREVENT in STL? C++ has no such thing.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You have a void* pointer which points to What?

Comment: I think he means SDL UserEvent http://linux.die.net/man/3/sdl_userevent

Comment: Show us the code that fills the UserEvent struct.

Comment: @Lewis : you've got a problem here.  By the time your eventhandler runs, `filename` is out of scope and `user.data1` is pointing to garbage.  You'll probably segfault (although, it _might_ work as expected... for awhile... until it segfaults).  Look at my answer to  see how to prevent that.

Comment: You're absolutely right, now that you point that out. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You just need to dynamically allocate it (because it probably needs to outlive the scope you're using it in), then cast it back and forth:

```
// Cast a dynamically allocated string to 'void*'.
void *vp = static_cast<void*>(new std::string("it's easy to break stuff like this!"));

// Then, in the function that's using the UserEvent:
// Cast it back to a string pointer.
std::string *sp = static_cast<std::string*>(vp);
// You could use 'sp' directly, or this, which does a copy.
std::string s = *sp;
// Don't forget to destroy the memory that you've allocated.
delete sp;
```

Comment: Note that this answer has an edge over the other(s), since it prevents the pointer's target from going out of scope. Thanks again!

Answer (score 13):

Based on your comment "What I meant was to convert what the void* is pointing to (which is a string) into a string."

Assuming you have this:

```
std::string str = ...;
void *ptr = &str;
```

You can just cast back to the string:

```
std::string *pstr = static_cast<std::string *>(ptr);
```

Note that it is on you to verify that `ptr` actually points to a `std::string`.  If you are mistaken and it points to something else, this will cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

If you trying to format the address as text you can use a `stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream strm;
strm << ptr;
std::string str = strm.str(); 

// str will now have something like "0x80004567"
```

If that's not what you are interested in, please clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear at all. What I meant was to convert what the void* is pointing to (which is a string) into a string.

Answer (score 0):

If the void is a const char*, then you can just call the std::string constructor with it, i.e.

```
const char* cakes = something;
std::string lols = std::string(cakes);
```

Comment: You can generally not assume this to be the case, so your suggestion would likely lead to a segmentation violation. Please consider removing it.

Comment: I tested this out of curiosity. It caused segmentation violation.