# converting void* pointing to char* to a std::string in c++

Tags: c++, string, void-pointers

From the wincrypt api I am receiving a void* pointing to a char*.
This char* is pointing to the start of a char[]. I am also receiving a `void*` pointing to a int with the size of the `char*`.

Regarding pvData and cbData I have the following documentation from Microsoft.

> Data type of pvData: A pointer to an array of BYTE values. The size of this array is specified in the cbData parameter. Returns a null-terminated Unicode character string that contains the display name for the certificate.

I want to convert this `void*` to a `std::string` but so far all I am getting when outputting my `std::string` is the first character.

I have read: [Converting a void* to a std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076968/converting-a-void-to-a-stdstring) but since my `void*` is pointing to a `char*` instead of `std::string` the `static_cast` in the accepted answer fails and the returned `std::string*` triggers a null pointer exception.

So far I have the following:

```
// pvData = void* pointing to char*
// cbData = void* pointing to int*
std::string tempName;
tempName.assign(static_cast<char*>(pvData), static_cast<int*>(cbData));
printf("%S \n", pvData); // entire string is shown
printf("%s \n", tempName.c_str()); // only first character is shown
```

I have also tried

```
tempName = static_cast<char*>(pvData); // only single character returned

tempName.assign(static_cast<char*>(pvData)); // only single character returned

char* arr = static_cast<char*>(pvData);
std::string tempName(arr); // only single character returned empty with printf must 
// use std::cout
```

Comment: Check the arguments passed to `std::string::assign`.

Comment: *"This char\* is a char[]"* What does that even mean?

Comment: And if you cast int* to int you have UB (or an unexpected value, at best). It's *cbData

Comment: @BaummitAugen that the char ptr is pointing to an array of characters in memory

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti you can't dereference a `void*`.

Comment: Is the `char` buffer null-terminated?

Comment: Go to the whiteboard an write 100 times: "an array is not a pointer, and a pointer is not an array".

Comment: *"I am also receiving a void\* pointing to a int..."* - then you need to cast that to an `int*` not an `int`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I changed it into: "This char* is pointing to the start of a char[]" that reads much beter right :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the char buffer isn't null-terminated, then to use the `(void*)cbData` length:

```
char* data = static_cast<char*>(pvData);
size_t len = *static_cast<int*>(cbData);
std::string tempName(data, len);
```

See the `std::string` [constructor reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) (#5, from buffer) and [`::assign` reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) (#4, buffer).

EDIT: If you're trying to use the function [CertGetCertificateContextProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376079(v=vs.85).aspx) with `dwPropId` `CERT_FRIENDLY_NAME_PROP_ID`, here is how you should call the function:

```
CERT_CONTEXT ctx;
BYTE buf[100];
DWORD len = 100;
CertGetCertificateContextProperty(&ctx, CERT_FRIENDLY_NAME_PROP_ID, buf, &len);
std::string tempName(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), len);
```

No dealing with `void*` pointers!

Comment: Kind sir you won the internet for today, I was close but no sigar. passing the int straight to std::string::assign instead of making it a size_t was the cause of the issue!

Comment: @Corne I think the issue was that you were casting the `void*` to an `int` when you should have cast it to an `int*`.

Comment: @Galik no that was a typo which I have removed to avoid confusing, sorry about that~!

Comment: @Corne See my edit – was this what you were trying to do?

Comment: @qyz yes the official example from microsoft showed it using void* no idea it could be this simple THANK YOU!.

Comment: np. With WinAPI functions (or other API functions) that take a `void*`, you generally are supposed to pass them just a normal pointer(-to-buffer) of the desired type.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation specifically states that it returns a Unicode string, which in Microsoft-speak means UTF-16. Characters that are part of the ASCII range will contain a zero in their second byte, which ends a string copy prematurely. You would get better results using `wstring` with a cast to `wchar_t*`.

If copying to string appears to work, it's because those zero bytes are invisible.

Putting this in the context of your original code:

```
std::wstring tempName;
tempName.assign(static_cast<wchar_t*>(pvData), (*static_cast<int*>(cbData)) / sizeof(wchar_t));
printf("%S \n", tempName.c_str());
```

Note that this isn't the easiest way to do it, you should also follow the [advice from qxz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39068599/5987) regarding the string constructor and the passing of `cbData`.

Comment: I also noticed this in my output because there is a space between each character now. This explains why copying while size_t is specified makes it  work. i'll be sure to switch to Unicode variables as described.