# How could I initialize LPVOID

Tags: c++

I have a function which should return me text.
This is the declaration:

```
typedef bool(WINAPI* GetMenuHelpName)(intptr_t dll, LPVOID lpBuffer, int size);
```

I suppose my text is in `LpBuffer`:

```
GetMenuHelpName func2 = (GetMenuHelpName)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "GetMenuHelpName");
LPVOID lpBuffer;
func2(instance, lpBuffer, 2048);
```

I got this error:

```
Error C4700 : uninitialized local variable 'lpBuffer' used
```

How could I initialize `lpBuffer` and put my result in a `std:string`?

Comment: Consider using `malloc` or initialize it like an array.

Comment: You have to allocate some memory for the buffer. You can't pass just a pointer to nothing and expect to get text back; you have to make the memory available, and it should match the size that you're telling it you're providing. Think about it - your current code says *Take this space I've not made available, and I'm telling you you can put 2048 bytes into that space that doesn't exist*. How exactly would you think that would work? Hint: It would work about as well as holding your empty hands out in front of you and telling someone *Shovel that manure into this bag I'm holding*.

Comment: Usually, if you plan to copy the data from the buffer, it would be a local array and you pass the address of that to the function then copy the data that is returned out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `LPVOID` type is exactly the same as `void*`, which means a pointer to something which doesn't have a specific type. Also, as it stands right now, lpBuffer isn't pointing at anything because it has not been initialized. There are two main ways to initialize this pointer: on the heap or on the stack. To initalize on the stack, initialize it like a `char` array:

```
char lpb[1000]; // Or however much space
LPVOID lpBuffer = (LPVOID) lpb;
```

To initialize on the heap, use the `malloc` (memory allocation) function. This allocates some space somewhere and returns a pointer to it. Just remember to call `free` on it when you're done to give that space back to the OS:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc, free

// ...

LPVOID lpBuffer = malloc(1000); // pick your space

// ...

free(lpBuffer);              // release the space
```

As for converting to a `std::string`, see this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076968/converting-a-void-to-a-stdstring).